# Authentication without server session

Tags: wicket

I like Wickets components and separation of HTML and code, but the stateful pages not so much. I am thinking of creating a Wicket app without server session state. I am not sure how to handle authenticated users, though. In other frameworks authentication can be handled by a signed cookie, which are validated on each request. Can this be achieved in Wicket? Or should I approach this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason why this should not work!

You just need custom IAuthenticationStrategy. You may use CookieUtils and ICrypt for the implementation.

Comment: Thx! Do you have any pointers on how to make Wicket stateless - meaning all data are reloaded on when going through browser history (for example back)?

Comment: Just keep you pages stateless. Use wicket-dev-utils' StatelessChecker for that.